# Get information about a function in python, looking at source code

Tags: python, numpy

the following code comes from the matplotlib gallery:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pylab import *

x = array([10, 8, 13, 9, 11, 14, 6, 4, 12, 7, 5])
y = array([8.04, 6.95, 7.58, 8.81, 8.33, 9.96, 7.24, 4.26, 10.84, 4.82, 5.68])
```

I am new to python, and would like to change the content of `x` and `y` from an input file. I have two short questions:

1. I could guess what `array` means,
   but once I see it on the code, how
   can I know to which library it
   belongs and more information about
   it? Should I use some kind of python
   debug commands?
2. How do I insert the content of my
   input file into `x`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As to your 1. that's due to bad habits of the person giving you that program. It should have been:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pylab

x = pylab.array([10, 8, 13, 9, 11, 14, 6, 4, 12, 7, 5])
y = pylab.array([8.04, 6.95, 7.58, 8.81, 8.33, 9.96, 7.24, 4.26, 10.84, 4.82, 5.68])

help(pylab.array)
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pylab import array

x = array([10, 8, 13, 9, 11, 14, 6, 4, 12, 7, 5])
y = array([8.04, 6.95, 7.58, 8.81, 8.33, 9.96, 7.24, 4.26, 10.84, 4.82, 5.68])

help(array)
```

Use the `help(something)`. It helps :)

Using explicit imports is really handy if programs become a bit more complex. The only case I know where `from package import *` is nice is when playing at the python prompt, trying stuff out.

As to the file, can you sketch how the file looks like? And I believe numpy has an array load function somewhere, look at the [cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/InputOutput).

Answer (score 1):

(1) Fire up the python console and use the dir() function on whatever object/class/variable you want to know more about. It'll print out all methods and properties of the object.

```
>> import pylab        
>> x =  pylab.array([10, 8, 13, 9, 11, 14, 6, 4, 12, 7, 5])
>> dir(x)
```

(2) look up [File Objects](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) in the python documentation

Comment: `dir` is inferior to `help` for finding out about an object.

Comment: Only if it's well documented :P

Answer (score 1):

- Use the `help` function to find out what an object can do.

  ```
  import pylab
  help(pylab.array)
  ```
- "What library it belongs to" is a sort of funny question. You can easily know what module you are using it from if you refactor your code not to use `import *`. (Never ever ever use `import *`.) That does not mean that's it's original home—`pylab` is just a place where a bunch of stuff is pooled for convenience. `pylab` gets it from `matplotlib.pylab` which gets it from `numpy` which gets it from `numpy.core.multiarray` (which is a C extension module). You can see its original home by looking at `pylab.array.__module__` when it's important, which is not often.

  - Personally, I think you're better of not using `pylab` at all, just getting stuff from `numpy`, `scipy`, and `matplotlib` as you need it to keep things organized. To quote The Zen of Python: *Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!*
- How to build an numpy array from a file depends on the format of the file. `numpy.fromfile`/`pylab.fromfile` can import a binary file storing the array's data. (This is the same format used by `numpy.tofile`—big shock there.)

Answer (score 0):

`array` appears to be a function/class in `pylab`. You could do `help(array)` to find out more - this relies on the presence of a proper docstring for `array`.

`from module import *` is a problematic idiom in several ways precisely for the reason that it makes it hard to find out where identifiers come from.

```
import pylab
x = pylab.array(...)
```

might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to question #2, if your file looks like this:

```
10 8.04
8 6.95
13 7.58
9 8.81
11 8.33
14 9.96
6 7.24
4 4.26
12 10.84
7 4.82
5 5.68
```

Then I would do like this:

```
x_list = list()
y_list = list()

fp = open('coords.txt', 'r')
for line in fp:
    line = line.strip()   # Remove trailing whitespace
    if not line: continue # Skip empty lines
    a,b = line.split()    # Split line by whitespace, storing coords in a & b
    x_list.append(a)      # Add a to x_list
    y_list.append(b)      # Add b to y_list
fp.close()

x = array(x_list)
y = array(y_list)
```